# Images not saving to App - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

I have recently created a small app, which is similar to a blog, allowing users to write articles, which include a Title, Body and an image upload. But I have ran into an issue regarding the images.
Using Paperclip gem I have added the upload option, however, once I have opened the app I have seen the image isnt actually there anymore when using a different machine. It just displays the name of the image
This works fine within my local machine (where the image is saved) so this leads me to think nothing is actually being stored sever wise, instead just storing somewhat of a link to the image in my directory.
Just tested using my Work PC, an image will save and display, but the ones I did last night (different PC will not). Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this issue? Not 100% sure where to look.

Comment: It is not clear, you can't access image when you run app on different machine, or if you try to access this image from different client machine?

Comment: Hello @StanislavMekhonoshin Yesterday I uploaded an Image from my Home PC and it displayed fine. However today when loading the App on my work PC, that original image is no longer displayed, it just states the name of the image. After further testing using my work PC, from myself and a colleague, we both uploaded an image and they are correctly displayed. But the original is still not, could this be a a directory linking issue instead of database? /system/articles/images/000/000/004/large/Prototype.PNG?1425456482 is the saved name for the image, showing it is saved on the server (I think)

Comment: Actually I didn't understand. Do you run app, and upload files to remote server with app, or you are running app on local machines?
If you run it on local machine, the you will not be able access files from other machine.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin I am running an app on a Heroku server, and when you click "New article" there is an option for images, and you just select the image you want to upload and submit.

Comment: Do you use S3 or something else to keep uploaded files?

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin The app is built on a Postgresql database, and Paperclip Gem is used for the image uploading feature.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from our discussion in comments, you use Heroku and paperclip.
Actually heroku has read-only filesystem, so you are unable to write to it.
That is why you can't access uploaded image. It is simply not written there.

The best way to handle this issue - to use external file storage. For example Amazon S3.

Paperclip has ability to upload to S3, just checkout this document http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Comment: So @StanislavMekhonoshin instead of pushing my application to Heroku, I would be pushing it to Amazon S3? Or would it be a mix of the two?

Comment: No, your app still will be running on heroku.
You should just configure PaperClip gem to upload files not on servers filesystem, but to remote S3.
Amazon S3 is just a static file storage, you uploads will be kept there.

Comment: Thank you @StanislavMekhinoshin I will give this a test tonight and hopefully this can resolve my issue :)

Comment: Will do, I will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: I have just tested briefly something with Heroku, when the app "Idles" it looses the ability to display the image, so the reason I saw it when at home was because the app had not gone idle, now that it has gone idle the images no longer display. Will Amazon S3 fix that issue also, so when the app is no longer idle the images will display? I am going to set up uptimerobot so that the App does not go idle.

Comment: No, heroku apps are always idle after some time of inactivity.
It is independent issue, not related with that it has read-only filesystem